# How to parse text between lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following text.

> Hello my name is Adam (age: 25) I live in US.
>
> Hello my name is Bill (age: 23) I live in Asia.

I want to get age and location from this text(with lookahead and lookbehind).

The output should be like this.

> `["25, US", "23, Asia"]`

This is how far i got.

`(?<=age: ).*?(?=$)`

With js match function i am getting this array.

> `["25) I live in US.", "23) I live in Asia."]`

I replaced `.*?` with `[0-9a-zA-Z]` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Be aware that lookbehind is not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question requested that the regex use *lookbehind* and *lookahead*. Frankly in this case there is no real need for this and it has been mentioned that not all browsers might support *lookbehind*. But if you were curious to see how it would look, here it is:

```
/^.*?(?<=age: )(\d+).*?(?<=I live in )([^.]+)(?=\.$).*?$/gm
```

1. `^` matches the beginning of the line.
2. `.*?` minimal match of 0 or more characters until:
3. `(?<=age: )(\d+)` matches 1 or more digits that are preceded by `'age: '` (you could make this `(?<=age: +)` to allow multiple spaces before the number).
4. `.*?` minimal match of 0 or more characters until:
5. `(?<=I live in )([^.]+)(?=\.$)` matches 1 or more non-period characters that are preceded by the string `'I live in '` and followed by a period and the end of line.
6. `.*?$` matches the remaining characters until the end of the line (this will be just a period).

```js
let s = `Hello my name is Adam (age: 25) I live in US.

Hello my name is Bill (age: 23) I live in Asia.`;

let regex = /^.*?(?<=age: )(\d+).*?(?<=I live in )([^.]+)(?=\.$).*?$/gm;
let result = s.replace(regex, `$1, $2`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
.*\bage:\s*(\d+)\s*\) I live in (.+)\.
```

would be a bit closer, in which there are two capturing groups with your desired substrings.

#### Test

```js
const regex = /.*\bage:\s*(\d+)\s*\) I live in (.+)\./gm;
const str = `Hello my name is Adam (age: 25) I live in US.
Hello my name is Bill (age: 23) I live in Asia.`;
const subst = `$1, $2`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oLFQ4y/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/oLFQ4y/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Nice one :) I was actually working on something simular based on your answer to my question about 2 months ago, haha.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I have hundreds of lines and your solution does not work with first and last line